# Splitting string into multiple strings using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, split

I am trying to split this string

```
string s = "sn DC0000002; mac 00:0c; uuid 564d6ae4-979";
```

I need to get these values from above string "**DC0000002**" , "**00:0c**" , "**564d6ae4-979**"

For this I have tried below query but not able to able to get last two values I mean these two values ("**00:0c**" , "**564d6ae4-979**")

Below is the query for splitting

```
List<string> decryptedList = new List<string>();
decryptedList = decodePP.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split(' ')[1]).ToList();

orgSNo = decryptedList[0]; //Output - DC0000002
orgMacID = decryptedList[1];// output - mac // this is wrong need to get value
orgUUID = decryptedList[2]; //output - uuid // this is also wrong
```

Would anyone please help on this query how extract values from the above string using LINQ query in a single shot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just trim substrings which you get after first split:

```
decodePP.Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim().Split(' ')[1]).ToList();
```

You get incorrect results, because first split gives you

```
[ "sn DC0000002", " mac 00:0c", " uuid 564d6ae4-979" ]
```

As you can see, items except first one have leading whitespace.

Alternative solution - you can use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` parameter to skip empty substrings

```
str.Split(';')
   .Select(x => x.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1])
   .ToList()
```

Comment: Actually, I like this better than my suggestion. Nice and concise. +1

Comment: Right answer. Of course 30 seconds of debugging on the part of the OP would have given him that answer.

Comment: i actually want only these values  DC0000002 00:0c 564d6ae4-979 as a individual strings ..

Comment: @pratapk So extract the first, second, and third items from the list like your original code does.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use Linq. The string split would seem to do the trick?

```
string[] keyValuePairs = s.Split(';');

foreach(string pair.Trim() in keyValuePairs)
{
   string key = pair.Split(' ')[0].Trim();
   string value = pair.Split(' ')[1].Trim();
}
```

That's only a stab at the code - it may not compile, but you get the idea?

Comment: Your code has the same bug that the original code does.

Comment: Yep - so it does. Missed the space after the space. Will edit for accuracy - won't change the fact that @Sergey Berezovskiy's answer was more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TrimStart() function in your linq statement like:

```
decryptedList = decodePP.Split(';').Select(x => x.TrimStart().Split(' ')[1]).ToList();
```